# Is there a function that transform from plain HTML to Hamlet structure?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I am starting to use the Yesod web framework. I have some already existing template HTML code that I would like to automatically translate to a Hamlet code structure. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What are the types of your existing code?

Comment: Plain HTML, for example, those taken from templates, with JS and CSS

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe this could help you [link](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/html/latest/doc/html/Text-Html.html#t:HTML), seems to have some kind of parsers

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which might do most of the work

```
perl -pe 'chomp' test.html | xmllint --format --encode UTF-8 - | perl -pe 's#</[^>]+>##g'
```

from https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Hamlet